# ol3 zoom with defined scale

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, scale, zoom

I am trying to show map based on the gridset defined in geoserver, in such a manner that map zooms to that Scale only.

Scale is as follow : 1:1000, 1:500, 1:400, 1:300

```
        view = new ol.View({
            center: [564878.4195196485, 4928488.1371189915],
            zoom: 16,
            projection: projection                
        })

        map = new ol.Map({
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attribution: false
            }).extend([mousePositionControl, scale]),
            layers: [L1, L2, L3, L4],
            target: 'map',
            view: view
        });
```

Comment: I think, i found the solution from this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/x5v9tkj8/34/)